# Use optional property of an interface as a type ( in openapi-typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, optional-chaining

How can I use a property of an interface as a type for a variable in typescript ??
Here I want to access the `property: string` type and use it as a type for a variable but I cannot access it.

```
interface foo {
  bar?: {
    baz: {
      property: string;
    };
  };
}

function f(input: foo['bar']['baz']['property']) {
  console.log(input);
}
```

I was trying to find some optional chaining rule for this, but none of the JavaScript chaining methods worked here.

Error

```
Property 'baz' does not exist on type '{ baz: { property: string; } ' | undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove  `| undefined` part from the `foo['bar']` type you can use [built-in `NonNullable` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype), then you can access its properties:

```js
function f(input: NonNullable<foo['bar']>['baz']['property']) {
  console.log(input);
}
```